# Remove overlapping values and keep the longest (with a threshold) within groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
   Groups  start   end  size
0      G1      1     5     5
1      G1      6    15     9
2      G1     25    50    25
3      G1     24    50    26
4      G1    100   120    20
5      G1     99   110    11
6      G1     98   110    12
7      G1    200   300   100
8      G1    295   400   105
9      G1    600   800   200
10     G1    594  1000   406
11     G2      1     6     6
12     G2      7    10     3
13     G2      3     4     1
14     G3      1    20     20  
15     G3      10   40     30  
16     G3      30   70     40
17     G3      36   70     40
```

And I would like for each `Groups` to remove overlapping coordinates of `start` and `end` positions, and **keep the longest** but by accepting some overlaps' length (**threshold** = keep if overlap `length <= 5`)

Here in that example, I should then get :

```
  Groups start end 
0 G1     1     5         <- keep    (no overlaps)
1 G1     6     15        <- keep    (no overlaps)
2 G1     25    50        <- remove  (overlap with [3] by length=25 but smaller then [3] )
3 G1     24    50        <- keep    (overlap with [2] by length=25 and larger then [3] )
4 G1     100   120       <- keep    (overlap with [5] and [6] by length=10 and 10 and larger than [6] and [7])
5 G1     99    110       <- remove  (overlap with [4] and [6] by length=10 and 11 but smaller than [4] and [6])
6 G1     98    110       <- remove  (overlap with [4] and [5] by length=10 and 11 but smaller than [4])
7 G1     200   300       <- keep    (overlap with [8] by length <=5, so I keep it)
8 G1     295   400       <- keep    (overlap with [7] by length <=5, so I keep it)
9 G1    600   800       <- remove  (overlap with [10] by length=200 and smaller than [10])
10 G1    594   1000      <- keep    (overlap with [9] by length=200 and larger than [9])
11 G2    1      6        <- keep    (overlap with [14] by length<=1, so I keep it)
12 G2    7      10       <- keep    (no overlaps)
13 G2    3      4        <- keep    (overlap with [11] by length<=1, so I keep it)
```

With then the expected output:

```
   Groups  start   end  size
0      G1      1     5     5
1      G1      6    15     9
2      G1     25    50    25
4      G1    100   120    20
5      G1     99   110    11
8      G1    295   400   105
9      G1    600   800   200
11     G2      1     6     6
12     G2      7    10     3
13     G2      3     4     1
```

---

**Answer about questions**

*define overlapping more precise*

Example

```
   Groups  start   end  size
0      G1      1     5     5
1      G1      6    15     9
2      G1     25    50    25
3      G1     24    50    26
```

[image]

*What do you want to do, when there is chaining: fe. 1st row overlapping with 2nd, 2nd overlapping with 3rd (but 1st do not overlap with 3rd itself): a) cluster them and took the longest b) took each pair individually?*

In that kind of example, I will take each pair individually.

Example :

```
       Groups  start end   size
14     G3      1    20     20  <- remove (overlap with [15] by length=10 but smaller than [15])
15     G3      10   40     30  <- keep (overlap with [14], [16] and [17] by length=10,10 and 4 and larger than [14] but overlap <= 5 with [17], so keep [17] )
16     G3      30   70     40 <- remove (overlap with [15] and [17] by length 10 and 34, larger than [17] but 17 is saved)
17     G3      36   70     40 <- keep  (overlap with [15], [16]  by length=4 and 34 but overlap <= 5 with [15], so keep it)
```

Here is an illustration to better understand this complicates example :

[image]

Can someone help me with that complicate code please ?

Here it the dataframe example in dict format if it can help you :

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G1', 6: 'G1', 7: 'G1', 8: 'G1', 9: 'G1', 10: 'G1', 11: 'G2', 12: 'G2', 13: 'G2', 14: 'G3', 15: 'G3', 16: 'G3', 17: 'G3'}, 'start': {0: 1, 1: 6, 2: 25, 3: 24, 4: 100, 5: 99, 6: 98, 7: 200, 8: 295, 9: 600, 10: 594, 11: 1, 12: 7, 13: 3, 14: 1, 15: 10, 16: 30, 17: 36}, 'end': {0: 5, 1: 15, 2: 50, 3: 50, 4: 120, 5: 110, 6: 110, 7: 300, 8: 400, 9: 800, 10: 1000, 11: 6, 12: 10, 13: 4, 14: 20, 15: 40, 16: 70, 17: 70}, 'size': {0: 5, 1: 9, 2: 25, 3: 26, 4: 20, 5: 11, 6: 12, 7: 100, 8: 105, 9: 200, 10: 406, 11: 6, 12: 3, 13: 1, 14: 20, 15: 30, 16: 40, 17: 40}}
```

Comment: What do you want to do, when there is chaining: fe. 1st row overlaping with 2nd, 2nd overlaping with 3rd (but 1st do not overlap with 3rd itself):
a) cluster them and took the longest
b) took each pair individually?

Comment: And could you please define overlapping more precise? (I'm not sure if I understand it correctly).

Comment: @DanielWlazło I edited the post with more examples and explanation, do not hesitate if something is still unclear for you. Thanks for your help and time.